# Are there left-handed wizards in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry Potter buys his wand, Ollivander asks him if he is right or left handed:

> "Well, now — Mr. Potter. Let me see.” He pulled a long tape measure with silver markings out of his pocket. “Which is your wand arm?”
>
> “Er — well, I’m right-handed,” said Harry.

Ollivander's question implies not all wizards are right handed, which brings me to my question: Are there left handed characters in Harry Potter? (Either described as such in the books or portrayed as such in the movies.)

**Edit:**
The reason I ask this question is that I know two girls who like role-playing in the Harry Potter world, and one of them uses a franchise wand (I guess, it is Hermione's) and the other (who is a leftie) says that she finds it uncomfortable to use… So I wondered if the story would give some reason to produce franchise wands for lefties. So, this question is not about left-handed monkey wrenches…

Comment: Are there left-handed wands? Or was that a joke, like left-handed monkey wrench?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Were-there-any-left-handed-witch-or-wizard-in-the-Harry-Potter-series

Comment: I don't think that asking about the hands used by the wizards in the movies really gives us an accurate representation of the wizard. The actor/tress will likely hold the wand in whatever is comfortable for them.

Comment: @CandiedMango: well, the question does say "portrayed as such in the movies". Seems a bit like arguing that John McClane might not "really" go bald over the course of the Die Hard franchise, it's just Bruce Willis ;-) What's in the movies is an accurate representation of the wizard in movie canon, albeit I'm willing to overlook Dumbledore's apparent polymorph from Harris to Gambon.

Comment: @SteveJessop But you're perfectly fine accepting Filius Flitwicks magical age reversion? :D

Comment: @CandiedMango: wasn't he murdered and badly impersonated by a musician, but everyone had more important things to worry about? But sure, movie canon is not always consistent in separate movies. With apologies to those for whom it's all real and hence there must be a Single True Version.

Comment: @LordVoldemort Oh, thanks for improving the questions! Looks much better after your edit.

Comment: Since this was my first question on this site, I would appreciate any comments on the downvotes.

Comment: @Dirk I wasn't a downvoter, but I suspect it probably attracted some downvotes because it could seem quite frivolous.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**There are no *confirmed* left-handed wizards or witches.**

- The [Quora link](https://www.quora.com/Were-there-any-left-handed-witch-or-wizard-in-the-Harry-Potter-series) posted by @LordVoldemort in the comments proposes an intriguing theory: Pettigrew could be left-handed.  At Voldemort’s rebirthing ceremony:

  > He stretched his right hand out in front of him — the hand with the missing finger. He gripped the dagger very tightly in his left hand and swung it upward.
  >
  > — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 32 (*Flesh, Blood and Bone*)

  So when Pettigrew faked his death, he cut off a finger from his right hand.  If you had to lose a finger, surely you’d choose to cut one from your non-dominant hand? Ergo, left-handed.

  The same argument could apply again: if you had to lose an entire hand, you’d want to keep your dominant hand. That he gives up his right hand suggests he’s probably not right-handed.
- There are actors who cast holding a wand in their left hand in some of the films – Neville Longbottom is the most prominent example – but it’s not clear whether this was an explicit decision from the filmmakers, or influenced by the actor’s dominant hand.

  According to a Matthew Lewis fanzine (Lewis is the actor who plays Neville) fansite, [he’s left-handed](http://matthew-lewis.com/index.php/matthew/facts/) – perhaps he was falling back to what he finds most comfortable?

  As such, I wouldn’t read too much into the films. (I believe the films are the source of the “Neville is left-handed” rumour.)

Comment: I assumed the opposite from Pettigrew's sacrifice for Voldemort: it has to be a real sacrifice from the servant for the master, and what greater sacrifice than one's *dominant* hand? All it says is "flesh of the servant", so there's no reason it has to be a hand at all - the choice of right hand is just to make it as great a sacrifice as possible.

Comment: @randal'thor I always assumed it was a callback to Voldy saying to Wormy in his dad's old house that "I will allow you to perform an essential task for me, one that many of my followers would give their **right hands** to perform…"(**GoF,Ch.1**, emphasis mine). Voldemort is self-absorbed enough to not care if Pettigrew is left-handed, so it would always be the *"right hand"* not the *dominant* one.

Comment: @randal'thor So why would he choose to cut off a finger on his dominant hand (which would require his non-dominant hand to hold the knife)?

Comment: I’ll freely admit that I’ve never tried to cut any of my own fingers off… but if I do attempt to even hold on to a knife and make the general movements presumably required to do so, I find it exceedingly difficult with my right hand, unless I put my finger on the table and pretend-cut it like I’d cut the food on a plate. The kind of dagger-swing described in the quote here would be a very messy business if I did it with my right hand—I wouldn’t have a clue how many fingers I’d be left with afterwards.

Comment: I could see the Pettigrew argument too. Not for what he cut off, but what hand he used to cut it off with.

Comment: I found a further hint that Wormtail is left-handed from *Half-Blood Prince* (Spinner's End): "His left hand was caressing his right, which looked as though it was encased in a bright silver glove." Logic suggests that he'd be most likely to caress his weaker hand with his dominant one.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Or he’s just developed a habit of caressing his fancy, magical silver hand because it’s a fancy, magical silver hand. He couldn’t very well use anything but his left hand for that, given which hand he cut off and had replaced.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, it's a hint, not definite proof. He could be stroking it because it's silver or because it's non-dominant or both.

Answer (score 23):

### Neville Longbottom

Is mentioned to be left-handed from the [Harry Potter wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Neville_Longbottom):

[image: Neville]
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2.

---

### Voldemort

In the movies at least, Voldemort is ambidextrous (the guy sure has skills):

[image: Volde right handed]
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2.

[image: Volde left handed]
Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire.

Comment: Does the HP wiki include a citation for this? It's notoriously unreliable as a primary source :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - ...the internet lied to me...?

Answer (score 5):

### Seraphina Picquery

According to [an article on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/fantastic-beasts-carmen-ejogo-seraphina-interview), the actress who portrayed President Seraphina Picquery wanted to make her character openly left-handed. The filmmakers agreed to this, along with her request to wear lots of prominent jewellery on her dominant left hand.

> *It was Carmen Ejogo’s idea to make her character, Seraphina,
> left-handed. The Selma actress has got a bit of a thing for history,
> and left-handedness has a long, complicated connection with magic.*
>
> *‘I’m left-handed actually, naturally, but I know that that’s a very
> magical trait. I’d be thought of as a witch years ago. So I wanted to
> really emphasize my left hand and I thought we could put rings on it.
> Colleen was really into that idea,’ Carmen says.*
>
> *She’s absolutely right, of course. Left-handedness has been associated
> with dark magic and sorcery for centuries. Joan of Arc was burnt at
> the stake in 1431 for heresy and there are several depictions of her
> as being left-handed.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Why Carmen Ejogo insisted her Fantastic Beasts character Seraphina was left-handed](https://www.pottermore.com/news/fantastic-beasts-carmen-ejogo-seraphina-interview)</sup></sub>

[image]